# Group Theory VS Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory

We all know that a quantum state or an observable, for example $|\phi>$ is a vector in Hilbert space.

What is the equivalent of a quantum state (or simply a state) in group theory?

Comment: This is totally unclear. Why should there be an analogue or equivalent to a quantum state in group theory?

Comment: Or.. why shouldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

States and Operators are very different.  More on that later.

A vector in a Hilbert Space is an element of a group (the group of vectors in the Hilbert Space with the operation of vector addition).  But not all elements of an arbitrary group correspond to a vector in a Hilbert Space.  Hilbert Spaces are specialized kinds of groups, with more operations besides addition and further properties/requirements.

There are other technical issues that might be barriers to an understanding of the relationship between quantum theory and group theory.

If you say a quantum state is a vector in a Hilbert Space, then only nonzero vectors can represent states.  And in that case an observable is a special kind of operator on that Hilbert Space, not a vector in that space.  A Hilbert Space is a special kind of vector space (one with an inner product, and where the inner product makes the space topologically complete).  A vector space is a special kind of group (one with a field of scalars, an additional operation of scalar multiplication where scaling a vector by a scalar gives another vector and the operation of scaling satisfies a bunch of very particular rules/requirements).

About terminology between mathematics and physics. When a mathematician says "group theory" (or set theory or ring theory, etc.) they mean a system of axioms and a deductive method that generates a collection of theorems.  It is entirely different than what physicists mean when they say they have a physical theory.

Finally, even the correspondence between quantum states and nonzero vectors in Hilbert spaces is not 100% unproblematic.  Not everyone will agree that a quantum state is a vector in a Hilbert Space, some people will say that you fix a Hilbert Space, and then the observables are certain operators on the Hilbert Space, and finally that a state is a certain kind of map from the operators.

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer to the question (mainly because the question doesn't make any sense).

Comment: @ACuriousMind I've edited the answer.